# Karaf update bundles via xml feature file

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

Scenario:

a feature xml file that describe an application (V1.0) with a bundle (suppose gson) version 2.2.3

A second feature file with a newer application (V1.1) version and with a gson bundle version 2.2.4

they will install gson 2.2.3 and 2.2.4 side-by-side.

Question:

is it possible by means of xml file (i've seen the xsd and no hints for me there) to UPGRADE from V1.0 to V1.1 AND uninstall at same time the unnecessary gson 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer no, there is no upgrade. You might install the new and uninstall the old this way unneeded bundles might be uninstalled. Still If your dependencies are right your bundle should pick-up only the new version and not the old.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with some limitations. Using a KAR file for the whole project as a unique artifact will do the trick. Limitation is that KAR files/url repositories must have same name.